# FB Log in OAuthException: (#803)

Tags: facebook-login, facebook-oauth

The connection between my SMForum and FB is happening but when i try to register on the app, it says :
OAuthException: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: me&fields=id,name,username
What does it mean ??
I have tried zillions of ways to connect my forum profile with FB but it keeps on giving me the same error!
Please...any help, suggestions or even blessings would be realy, REALY, appreciated !!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error 803 on previously working query - " Some of the aliases you requested do not exist"](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13825707/error-803-on-previously-working-query-some-of-the-aliases-you-requested-do-n)

Answer (score 1):

> OAuthException: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: me&fields=id,name,username

It means using that call is unsupported.

Most likely you meant

```
graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,username
```

Notice the `?` and not `&`

Comment: I did not know how to change the ? into the & but i uninstalled the old version of SA Facebook plugin "2.0 RC4 Rev58" for SMF and installed the curent SA Facebook Packet and IT WORKED!!!!!!!!!!!
Thank you so much guys!!!! 
Realy, Thank you!